# I cant get the result of y

Tags: matlab, math

I have this questions but my result is different with the exact result what is the wrong?

[image]

this is what i tried.

```
x = 2;
z = 3;
y = x^2*x*z+12*x*z+((exp(x)/log(x*z)-log(x*z)*nthroot(x*z,2)))*nthroot(x*z,3);
```

result of y is 95.5185 not equal to -21.455

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### MATLAB Logarithm Conventions

Breaking up long equations into separate terms is useful for debugging. Here the case was the logarithmic functions that were used.

*log* → `log10()` (base-10 logarithm)
*ln* → `log()` (natural logarithm)

```
x = 2;
z = 3;
Term_1 = (x^2)*x*z;
Term_2 = 12*x*z;
Term_3 = (exp(x))/(log(x*z) - log10(x*z)*sqrt(x*z));
Term_4 = nthroot(x*z,3);

y = Term_1 + Term_2 + Term_3*Term_4;
y
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**